# Excel Function Error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am stuck on an excel formula that I feel is easy but is just messing with me. Below is my problem:

As you can see I have inputted a formula for IF Actual CTR has not date then extract the data from Drive To CTR. When the field does not have a Actual it does pull from Drive To but if Actual has a date then False is inputted? I want the date to show in Actual CTR not False?

My current formula is

```
=IF(ISBLANK([@[Actual CTR]]),[@[Drive To CTR]])
```

[image]

Comment: What version of Excel?  And can you copy and paste the formula from the worksheet into your post?

Comment: Currently using Excel 2013. This is my current formula

=IF(ISBLANK([@[Actual CTR]]),[@[Drive To CTR]])

Comment: Can you add a comma at the end of your formula and add the value for if false?  An Excel IF function should read like =IF (logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false]) and I think you have omitted the false condition to evaluate, and the value if true, but omit the value if false from your function.  So something like this =IF(ISBLANK([@[Actual CTR]]),[@[Drive To CTR]],[@[Actual CTR]])   https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-if-function

Comment: Perfect! I knew it would be an easy fix - I missed the last part of the formula causing the error and that was causing the False statement.

Comment: Glad I could help.  I posted my comment as an answer since it helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you add a comma at the end of your formula and add the value for if false?

An Excel IF function should read like `=IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])` and I think you have omitted the false condition to evaluate.

Try something like this `=IF(ISBLANK([@[Actual CTR]]),[@[Drive To CTR]],[@[Actual CTR]])`

Here is a link providing further information on the Excel If function
[Excel If Function](http://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-if-function)